# Omit Simplenews Subscribers Who Responded from Follow Up Email

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using D7 and [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews). I have a newsletter category mynewsletter with 1000 subscribers.  In my most recent mynewsletter, I had a poll.  200 subscribers have responded.  I want to send a reminder to the remaining 800.  I know i could manually exclude these 200 from the list and then add them back, but I plan to do this frequently.

Is there a hook i can use before the newsletter is spooled that will allow me to eliminate the users in the list who have already responded? The email addresses of respondents is in the database, so i can compare against the list.

Anyone done something like this or have ideas?